# Specify Header and Footer for all file created by MultiResourceItemWriter when writing in multiples files -spring batch

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-batch, writer

I have a batch that read from data base using JdbcPagingItemReader, process each record from the database in a java class then write it to a file using FlatFileItemWriter. **It appends also a header and footer** for this file using `FlatFileFooterCallback` and `FlatFileHeaderCallback`

The Job work well and it gives as output, a single JSON file in this format :

```
{"informations":[
{
 "name" : "xxx",
 "adress" : "xxx"
  //a very complex json object (1000 lines)
},
{
   "name" : "xxx",
 "adress" : "xxx"
  //a very complex json object (1000 lines )
},

// Many objects
]}
```

Kindly note that the header is just this :

```
{"informations":[
```

And the footer is just

```
]}
```

now the file is too big and I want to split it to multiple file using `MultiResourceItemWriter`
Each file has at maximum 1000 row read from the database.

So I configured the step and I used the first FlatFileItemWriter above and this work well.
As result, I have many files that have 1000 records from a data base but **without the header and the footer**
`{"informations":[`  and  `]}`

All files generated by **MultiResourceItemWriter** have this format :

```
{
 "name" : "xxx",
 "adress" : "xxx"
  a very complex json object (1000 lines)
},
{
   "name" : "xxx",
 "adress" : "xxx"
  a very complex json object (1000 lines )
},
{
// many objects
}
```

How could I add the header and the footer for all files created by `MultiResourceItemWriter` When writing.

I found an answer that say that we can't combine MultiResourceItemWriter with FlatFileItemWriter that have `FlatFileFooterCallback` and `FlatFileHeaderCallback` with spring batch version **< 2.1** .

[Stream closed exception when combining MultiResourceItemWriter and FlatFileItemWriter with footer callback](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/2111) and stack overflow post [stack-overflow-post-about-my-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804042/spring-batch-java-io-ioexception-stream-closed-exception-when-combining-multir)

I have this exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: JsonWriter is closed` when trying to wrap `FlatFileItemWriter` with `FlatFileHeaderCallback`  in my final `MultiResourceItemWriter`  writer.

So is there a way to specify a header and footer for all file created by `MultiResourceItemWriter` when writing in a new file (splitting to multiple file) ? Is there a way to define a template of the file in which the `MultiResourceItemWriter`  write in?

If no, could you please guide me to do so?

I would like to have in final, all file that created by MultiResourceItemWriter have at the beginning the
`{"informations":[` and at the end `]}` , all the file content is wrapped in the json array `informations`.

Answer (score 2):

> How could I add the header and the footer for all files created by MultiResourceItemWriter When writing.

You need to set the header/footer callbacks on your delegate writer. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileFooterCallback;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileHeaderCallback;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceSuffixCreator;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.MultiResourceItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Integer> itemWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Integer> flatFileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Integer>()
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                .name("itemsWriter")
                .headerCallback(writer -> writer.write("header"))
                .footerCallback(writer -> writer.write("footer"))
                .build();

        return new MultiResourceItemWriterBuilder<Integer>()
                .delegate(flatFileItemWriter)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("items"))
                .itemCountLimitPerResource(5)
                .resourceSuffixCreator(index -> "-" + index + ".txt")
                .name("multiResourcesWriter")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .<Integer, Integer>chunk(5)
                        .reader(itemReader())
                        .writer(itemWriter())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

This generates two files `items-1.txt` and `items-2.txt` with the following content:

```
header
1
2
3
4
5
footer
```

and

```
header
6
7
8
9
10
footer
```

> I use spring batch version 3.0.10.RELEASE

This version is not maintained anymore, so I encourage you to upgrade to the latest and greatest v4.3.1. The example above uses Spring Batch v4.3.1 and works as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud but I have already tried that and  I got this exception : ERROR o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep - Exception while closing step execution resources in step step4 in job java.lang.IllegalStateException: JsonWriter is closed.

Comment: Your delegate is `<property name="delegate" ref="singleEventItemWriter" />` which is of type `com.xx.xx.CustomFlatFileItemWriter`. You did not share the complete code of that custom writer, so the issue seems to be related to your code since it works as expected with the built-in `FlatFileItemWriter` provided by Spring Batch.

Comment: Here is my MyCustomFlatFileItemWriter as you asked:

Comment: I added the code of the customFlatItemWriter as you asked, and I added the stack trace of the exception. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update. From your stacktrace I see `[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] ERROR o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep ...` Is your step multi-threaded? I don't see that in your xml config (no `task-executor` element) but I want to make sure it is not the case (probably a copy/paste issue). Because if your step is multi-threaded, that explains the problem: two threads could be calling `jsonWriter.close` and one of them fails with this exception. The `FlatFileItemWriter` is *not* thread safe and should be synchronized if used in a multi-threaded step.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud for you response. Yes I used split to parallelize job flow. I have edit my post. I added all the config of my job that I have used. Thanks

Comment: That's a very important detail that should have been in the question from the beginning to be able to help you in an efficient way. `The writer CusXxWriter didn't use the The class MyCustomItemHeaderFooterWriter but it uses the jsonWriter`: sorry, but I can't follow anymore, please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. I can't debug your code as is but I will give you some hints: In a multi-threaded environment, you need to make sure that your writer is thread safe.