# StaxEventItemWriter for spitting big XML files with header

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch, stax

I have a requirement to migrate some old java batches to spring batch. This old batches are reading big XML files ( >1gb ) and splitting them to small XML files. So we have the following scenario:

1. Input: Big1File.xml -> Output: Small1.1File.xml , Small1.2File.xml ,
   Small1.3File.xml
2. Input: Big2File.xml -> Output: Small2.1File.xml , Small2.2File.xml
3. Input: Big3File.xml -> Output: Small3.1File.xml , Small3.2File.xml ,
   Small3.3File.xml , Small3.4File.xml

The structure of this xml files is always the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <info>
  <header>
   <headerField1></headerField1>
   <headerField2></headerField2>
  </header>
  <elements>
   <element>
    <elementField1></elementField1>
    <elementField2></elementField2>
    <elementField3></elementField3>
   </element>
   <element>
    <elementField1></elementField1>
    <elementField2></elementField2>
    <elementField3></elementField3>
   </element>
   <element>
    <elementField1></elementField1>
    <elementField2></elementField2>
    <elementField3></elementField3>
   </element>
   <element>
    <elementField1></elementField1>
    <elementField2></elementField2>
    <elementField3></elementField3>
   </element>
    ....
  </elements>
 </info>
```

I've been reading documentation and examples regarding StaxEventItemReader and StaxEventItemWriter and I'm not sure if I can use the default version of the Writer.

Are StaxEventItem Classes a good choice to split this type of xml files?

Usually the examples are xml without the header elements, basically xmls with list of elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <info>
  <elements>
   <element>
    <elementField1></elementField1>
    <elementField2></elementField2>
    <elementField3></elementField3>
   </element>
   <element>
    <elementField1></elementField1>
    <elementField2></elementField2>
    <elementField3></elementField3>
   </element>
   <element>
    <elementField1></elementField1>
    <elementField2></elementField2>
    <elementField3></elementField3>
   </element>
   <element>
    <elementField1></elementField1>
    <elementField2></elementField2>
    <elementField3></elementField3>
   </element>
    ....
  </elements>
 </info>
```

If I'm not wrong what I will need to do is extend StaxEventItemWriter and then I will be able to add the header for each of the output files, am I correct?

Comment: It's a viable approach, but why not save yourself a lot of low-level coding and use a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformation instead?

Comment: What is your criteria to split the files? Is it the number of elements, the size of output files, etc? Is the header the same for all input files (Big1File.xml, Big2File.xml, etc) or do you need to parse it dynamically from each input file?

Comment: Thanks for asking @MichaelKay but I think that with StaxEventItems I can do it quite easily!

Comment: Thanks for asking @MahmoudBenHassine ! Right now the criteria is the number of elements. For example splitting every big file in smaller files with only 5k elements. The header is different for every big file and I have to put this header in each small file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [MultiResourceItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemWriter.html) that delegates to a `StaxEventItemWriter`. To limit the number of elements per file, you can set the `itemCountLimitPerResource` parameter to 5000.

For the header, you need to create a separate step that extracts it dynamically from the file and pass it to the delegate writer. I shared an example with a flat file writer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938415/5019386), but you can adapt it for an xml writer.